# Object does not exist in the pdf file structure

Tags: parsing, pdf

```
%PDF-1.5
...
10737 0 obj
<</MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 161 0 R/PageLayout/OneColumn/Pages 10732 0 R/StructTreeRoot 206 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
10738 0 obj
<</Contents[10740 0 R 10741 0 R 10747 0 R 10748 0 R 10749 0 R 10750 0 R 10751 0 R 10752 0 R]/CropBox[0.0 0.0 516.0 728.64]/MediaBox[0.0 0.0 516.0 728.64]/Parent 10733 0 R/Resources<</ColorSpace<</CS0 10771 0 R/CS1 10772 0 R>>/ExtGState<</GS0 10773 0 R>>/Font<</C2_0 10778 0 R/C2_1 10783 0 R/C2_2 10788 0 R/C2_3 10793 0 R/C2_4 10798 0 R/TT0 10800 0 R/TT1 10802 0 R/TT2 10804 0 R/TT3 10806 0 R/TT4 10808 0 R>>/XObject<</Im0 10769 0 R>>>>/Rotate 0/StructParents 0/Tabs/S/Type/Page>>
endobj
10739 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/First 410/Length 3756/N 38/Type/ObjStm>>stream
10771 0 10772 21 10773 42 10774 138 10775 190 10776 442 10777 741 10778 752 10779 869 10780 921 10781 1190 10782 2050 10783 2061 10784 2192 10785 2244 10786 2504 10787 3456 10788 3467 10789 3587 10790 3639 10791 3903 10792 6058 10793 6069 10794 6196 10795 6248 10796 6507 10797 8153 10798 8164 10799 8284 10800 8496 10801 9662 10802 9894 10803 11072 10804 11325 10805 11779 10806 11985 10807 13147 10808 13395 
[/ICCBased 10753 0 R][/ICCBased 10754 0 R]
<</AIS false/BM/Normal/CA 1.0/OP false/OPM 1/SA true/SMask/None/Type/ExtGState/ca 1.0/op false>>
<</Ordering(Identity)/Registry(Adobe)/Supplement 0>><</Ascent 858/CIDSet 10757 0 R/CapHeight 719/Descent -148/Flags 4/FontBBox[-16 -148 1008 858]/FontFamily(\xfe\xff\x00H\x00Y\xc9\x11\xac\xe0\xb5\x15)/FontFile2 10758 0 R/FontName/YDRADB+H2gtrM/FontStretch/Normal/FontWeight 400/ItalicAngle 0/StemV 60/Type/FontDescriptor/XHeight 520>>
...
endstream
endobj
...
```

No. - Type
10732 - Pages
206   - StructTreeRoot
10771, 10772, 10773, 10778 ... - Font

Many indirect objects including 10732, 206, 10771 and 10772 do not exist in the pdf file.
But I think I found objects 10771~10808 in object 10739 stream.

Q1. Why are there no object 10732(Pages) and 206(StructTreeRoot) in the pdf file?
Q2. Why are indirect objects in stream?

I would be grateful if you would suggest any explanations or resources for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version 1.5 PDF supports so called object streams, i.e. stream objects which contain other non-stream objects.

Your object 10739 is such an object stream as you can see in its **Type** **ObjStm**.

This allows those other objects to be compressed. In particular structure tree objects which otherwise can substantially increase the size of a PDF, can be compressed fairly well, reducing their impact on the document size.

For details please study the PDF specification, section 7.5.7 – *Object Streams*, in either the current PDF specification ISO 32000-2 or its predecessor ISO 32000-1.

Adobe has shared a copy of ISO 32000-1 on their web site which merely has its ISO page headers replaced. Simply google for "PDF32000_2008"; currently it is located at https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf but as far as I know this isn't a permalink.

Comment: I am working on an urgent project, so I couldn't read the entire document. Thank you for writing down what I need.